# How to make a custom Arrow Back height and width in Flutter

Tags: flutter, mobile, flutter-layout

I want to make a custom back arrow with a specific height and width, how can I achieve that in flutter? I tried wrapping the `IconButton` with `SizedBox` and `Container` but none of those work. This is the current back arrow from the `Icon(Icons.arrow_back)`:

[image]

But I wanted to make it more like this:

[image]

The straight line of the arrow is a little longer and the head of the arrow is a little shorter than the default one. Any suggestions on how to achieve this? Should I use another icon or can I make customize the already given one by default?
The code:

```
AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              elevation: 0.0,
              iconTheme: IconThemeData(
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              title: new Text('Back Arrow')
              leading: IconButton(
                color: Color(0xFF323232),
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_back,
                ),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
              ),
            ),
```

Thanks in advance for the help and suggestions!

Comment: I think that it can be done by a designer only .... but you can try to find the icon in FlutterAwesomeIcons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant customise inbuilt icons in flutter, you need to create your own icons. There is `size` property in `Icon` widget which grows both width and height but it will not satisfy your need.

You can download icons from below sites:

[Flaticon](https://www.flaticon.com/)

[Icons8](https://icons8.com/)

and check this [blog](https://medium.com/codechai/how-to-use-custom-icons-in-flutter-834a079d977) to use custom icons in flutter